# Clicking particular element in a drop down list

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors

Can you please help me click on an item in a drop down list. I have a class called prompt-wrapper which contains user names. I want to click a particular user.

In the example below I have only one user but the list can have multiple users. Here I want to click on "Janice Hunt".

```
<div class="prompt-wrapper" data-reactid=".0.0.3.0.$message-panel.2.2">
    <div class="prompt-item selected hover" data-reactid=".0.0.3.0.$message-panel.2.2.1:$user_950413">
        <div class="prompt-item-avatar" data-reactid=".0.0.3.0.$message-panel.2.2.1:$user_950413.0">
            <img src="/bundles/neighbourlyregistration/img/avatar.png" data-reactid=".0.0.3.0.$message-panel.2.2.1:$user_950413.0.0">
        </div>
        <span class="prompt-item-name" data-reactid=".0.0.3.0.$message-panel.2.2.1:$user_950413.1"><strong>Janice</strong> Hunt</span>
        <span class="prompt-item-address" data-reactid=".0.0.3.0.$message-panel.2.2.1:$user_950413.2">
        <span class="glyph  icon glyphicon-marker" data-reactid=".0.0.3.0.$message-panel.2.2.1:$user_950413.2.0"></span>
        <span data-reactid=".0.0.3.0.$message-panel.2.2.1:$user_950413.2.1">&nbsp;</span><span data-reactid=".0.0.3.0.$message-panel.2.2.1:$user_950413.2.2">Suburb</span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can locate the desired item in the dropdown by XPath:

```
//span[@class="prompt-item-name" and strong = "Janice" and contains(., "Hunt")]
```

Don't forget to click the dropdown to open it up before selecting an item.

Comment: Worked a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you need to click on a particular value in drop down use the below code, if there are many values in the drop down field.

```html
//get the drop down field first via id, name, className, cssSelector etc...
  WebElement propertySelectBox = browser.findElement(By.className("txtfld"));
//Use 'Select' statement 
  Select propertyComboBox = new Select(propertySelectBox);
// 4 means 5th Element
  propertyComboBox.selectByIndex(4);
```